# Value of bootstrap dropdown do not change

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap drop down with exactly similar in behaviour to html select drop down. But on the `bootstrap` website, I none of the drop downs actually change it's value in the span or input tab, when I change the drop down.

Also I am looking for the change event to occur when I change the item.

Yet I tried to map as much as possible:

I am doing the following:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-select="true">
      <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class='dropdown-display'>5</span>
        <i class='caret'></i>
      </a>
      <input type='hidden' value='5' class='dropdown-field spec-no-of-rows' />
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="10">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="20">20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="50">50</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="100">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="500">500</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="1000">1000</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have included boostrap and bootsrap-dropdown and bootsrap-select.

When I click on the box, no dopdown appears, neither any event is triggerred. what wrong I am doing.

So can I have exactly same behaviour of html select in bootstrap?

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle or something to put up a demo showing your code (including javascript)? It'll be a lot easier for us to debug it. Also, why not just use an actual `select` element?

Comment: Why would you expect the Bootstrap dropdown to change the original value? It's purpose is as a popout menu, not a `<select>` replacement. You're going to have to write some of your own JS, or just use a `<select>`

Comment: make a fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: currently i am having this : http://jsfiddle.net/XmYeA/

Comment: keep look on this : http://jsfiddle.net/NzvKC/87/

Comment: updated with liberaries : http://jsfiddle.net/NzvKC/89/

Answer (score 1):

i had forgot to add in my javascript :

```
$('div[data-select=true]').dropSelect();
```

Now everything works smooth.